# Refering to a Cell in a Different Workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I work between different spreadsheets, and I like to have one main workbook that links to certain cells in other workbooks.

For example, I will do a statement of business activities workbook that has all the business expenses listed, and then I will have individual workbooks for each expense account.

In the old excel, I would just put

`=(and then go to the workbook that i wanted, and then select the cell i wanted and then hit enter)`

and it would put the amount from that specific cell in my statement of business activities.

When I try to do that in excel 2010, I put the equals sign in the cell, and then go to the other workbook and find the cell I want, and when I hit enter, it just moves down a line and nothing happens in the other workbook.

How can I get this to work again, what do i need to do??

Answer (score 4):

Check if you have two instances of Excel running with a workbook open in each instance. If so, they won't be able to "communicate" with each other and you won't be able to create external links between them.

To fix this, you may either:

- Close the other workbook. With only one instance remaining, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> or **File** > **Open** to re-open the workbook that you've just closed.

  *or*
- Close both workbooks first, open one and then when Excel is up, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> or **File** > **Open** to launch the other one.

Comment: How do I open both in a single instance?

Comment: @Anna Close the other workbook. With only one instance remaining, use CTRL+O or File>Open to re-open the workbook you just closed.

Comment: @Anna You could also close both workbooks first, open one and then when Excel is up, use CTRL+O or File>Open to launch the other one.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept this answer by clicking the 'check' mark to the left of this panel.  (For more info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: NB: It seems that this is no longer an issue in Excel 2013; i.e. this allows a single instance of Excel with multiple open workbooks to behave in the same way as multiple instances; that is you can work with multiple monitors and have workbooks communicate with one another as expected without having to open the workbooks in a specific way.

Answer (score 1):

Issue still persists in 2016-O365.  If an instance of Excel is first launched via hyperlink to a CSV file, and a second is launched via File Explorer, the sheets won't talk to each other.  This is true even if you first save the CSV to XLSX format on the same logical drive.  To fix this, save & close the hyperlink-launched Excel instance and reopen the file via File Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this and as a matter of fact; if you know all the workbooks you are using are trustworthy. You can go to the trustcenter and change the settings.

file> options> trust center> trust center settings> trusted documents> **click on disable trusted documents> ok

This allows the workbooks to communicate without any issue.

**********discard this*******************

Comment: If you are trying to retract this answer, because you have discovered that it is wrong, look below the answer, toward the left, for a ‘‘Delete’’ link, and click it.  It that doesn’t work, please say something more explicit, like “This answer is wrong; please ignore it.”

Answer (score 0):

This helps me

In Excel 2010 and below,

Go to "Excel Options" → "Advanced" → "Display",
Uncheck "Show all windows in the Taskbar",
Click "OK" to close the Options window.
Now Alt+Tab should work fine again.